# Verilog: Range must be bounded by constant expression

Tags: fpga, verilog

I have one doubt. The error is: `Range must be bounded by constant expression` when compiling the below lines:

```
X=in[i+2 : i] +1'b1;
In[i]=-1;
```

Please tell how to resolve it.

Answer (score 1):

The width of ranges must be a constant and must be written this way: `in[i+:3]`

See [Accessing rows of an array using variable in Verilog](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/67983/accessing-rows-of-an-array-using-variable-in-verilog/67988#67988)

Comment: Thank you so much.... The code is compiled without error...

Answer (score -1):

Remember that Verilog is not a general purpose programming language, it is a **hardware description** language. Once the hardware is synthesized, or compiled, it generally does not change. So, the code you use to specify the hardware must specify fixed hardware.

Rather than use run-time variables to select the inputs to an adder you must use a multiplexer to select those inputs. The control signals for the multiplexer would be derived from whatever logic you use to choose the value of `i` in your original code.